# GO PQ driver cannot query with default schema

Tags: go, pq

Code to open connection to DB:

```
DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", "dbname=dev user=postgres password=postgres port=5400 sslmode=disable")
```

I'm trying to do a simple *select query* like:

```
err := DB.QueryRow("SELECT id FROM user WHERE id = $1", id)
```

but I get the error: *pq: column id does not exist*

However, if I try with the *schema*:

```
err := DB.QueryRow("SELECT id FROM public.user WHERE id = $1", id)
```

it goes fine. I don't understand why I must write the *schema* even though the *default schema* is *public* in the *postgresql* I'm running on *Docker*

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code that you used to initiate the connection with postgresql? A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help us to replicate the problem on our end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` is a reserved keyword of postgres that is used to get information about the current database user. When you run a query like `SELECT * FROM user`, it retrieves information about the current database user, not the data from a table named `user`.

But with `SELECT id FROM public.user` this, it will get the result from `user` table of `public` schema. This ensures that PostgreSQL looks specifically in the `public` schema for the `user` table and retrieves the desired data.

**Solutions**

1 - Rename your table into `users`

2 - Or use the schema name along with the query.

**References** :

- [SQL Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

Answer (score -1):

check the default search_path with this SQL :

```
SHOW search_path;
```

if it is not public then set it:

```
ALTER ROLE your_user SET search_path = public;
```